# Jetpack compose LazyColumn+Coil-Compose doesn't work

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack compose project

I use Coil-Compose rememberImagePainter

dependencies {

```
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0'
```

}

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ApplicationTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Image(
                        painter = rememberImagePainter("https://api.dujin.org/bing/1366.php"),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK20L.jpg)

add LazyColumn doesn't work

```
…………
import coil.compose.rememberImagePainter
…………

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ApplicationTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
+                   LazyColumn {
+                       items(10) {
                            Text(text = "test")
                            // doesn't work
                            Image(
                                painter = rememberImagePainter("https://api.dujin.org/bing/1366.php"),
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
+                       }
+                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ky5m.png)

Please help me

Comment: look like your image url is broken. I tried to access https://api.dujin.org/bing/1366.php but it said "Web server is down"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In LazyColumn or LazyRow is no problem with local resources, but network pictures you need to specify the width and height

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ApplicationTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                   LazyColumn {
                       items(10) {
                            Text(text = "test")
                            // doesn't work
                            Image(
                                painter = rememberImagePainter("https://api.dujin.org/bing/1366.php"),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                Modifier.fillMaxSize().height(300.dp)
                            )
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `fillMaxSize` already specify the height?

Answer (score 1):

if useful for you too, I've solved this problem with recovering images with Coil from remote resources putting in lazycolumn/lazyrow

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.5f),
```

with different percentage.